# What does "de la fila" mean in this context?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

Listening to a Spanish radio station this morning, they were counting up the top 10 songs. With at least several of them, they would say, "de la fila" such as: "...Numero cinco, de la fila"

Google translate says this means "row". I was thinking, by the context, it corresponded to "with a bullet" or "moving up this week" something like that. Am I right?

Comment: in ur column or row, u have the 5th position in the cue, yep?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que no han dicho "el último de la fila"?

Comment: The accepted answer is correct on this context but FYI another meaning for "fila" is **queue** like when you go to the bank and have to _stand in queue_. This in Spanish would be "hacer la fila en el banco".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that *de la fila* means "of the list" (i.e. the top 10), although the normal thing would have been *de la lista*, at least in Spain.

Comment: That makes sense; that was the context.

Comment: I would more say that file corresponds to the "line/queue", than to a "list". It implies somehow "order" or "sorting" in the expression